# Want to show all icon in ListView of flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, icons

I want to make a screen that displays all available flutter icons

can anyone suggest me for loop coding for showing all flutter default icon list in ListView  Icon and Icon name

Comment: Post your best effort so far.

Comment: see if there is a list of all icons in the codebase, if not you might have to do it manullay.

Comment: Please attach the image you want to complete and the source you created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this link https://github.com/Ahmadre/FlutterIconPicker/blob/master/lib/IconPicker/Packs/Material.dart and get all the available flutter icons, and list using listview.

The above link contains all the icon variables with the respective names.

```
Map<String, IconData> icons_data = {
 'ac_unit': Icons.ac_unit,
 'ac_unit_sharp': Icons.ac_unit_sharp,
 'ac_unit_rounded': Icons.ac_unit_rounded,
 'ac_unit_outlined': Icons.ac_unit_outlined,
  ect...
}


ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: icons_data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var item = icons_data.entries.elementAt(index);
        return Row(
          childern:[
           Text(item.key + " - "),
           Icon(item.value)
          ]
        );
      },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**There is no flutter API to get all flutter Icons.** Developers can access all those default icon one by one. you can make a list of icon by youself.
for example:

```
  static const _iconList = <IconData>[
    Icons.cake,
    Icons.add_location_sharp,
    Icons.zoom_in_outlined,
    Icons.auto_awesome_motion,
    Icons.call_end_sharp,
    Icons.equalizer_rounded,
    Icons.wifi_lock,
    Icons.mail,
    etc................,
  ];
```

Use the list in listView as like

```
 ...
     Container(
      child: ListView(
        children: _iconList .map((icon) => Icon(icon)).toList(),
      ),
    )
    ...
```

You can go through all flutter icons from bleow links.

**Default Material Icons:** https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html

**Flutter custom icons generator:** https://www.fluttericon.com/

**FontAwesomeIcons:** https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter

**other link :**  https://www.fluttericon.com/